# Simple boolean expression parser in Spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've come up with following boolean expression parser after reading the Spirit tutorials:

```
expression =
          bool_                           [_val =  _1]
            >> *(  ("&&" >> expression    [_val && _1])
                |  ("||" >> expression    [_val || _1])
                )
            ;
```

For constants I get the correct results from the parser:

> true -> 1
>
> false -> 0

But for slightly more complex expressions things go horribly wrong:

> true && false -> 1 (incorrect!)
>
> false && true -> 0 (correct)
>
> false || true -> 0 (incorrect!)
>
> true || false -> 1 (correct)

Comment: Do you notice a pattern in the correct/incorrect output? Like `false` first in the expression always seems to result in `false`, and `true` first in the expression always seems to result in a `true` result?

Comment: There seem to be no "&&=" and "||=" operators...

Comment: Sorry Boris - should just use `&=` and `|=`, or `_val = _val && _1` etc..  The point is you're not changing `_val` in your action.  After that you can work on precedence etc..

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thanks! With precedence you mean right to left parsing?